# How to return background result?

Tags: java, android

I did the code in android to retrieve records from website url. But I am stuck in receiving the result in string variable.

I want to display received values in receiveddata variable. Please help me on this..

I did this code:

Main2Activity.java

```
    btnsync.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        String receiveddata="";

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Syncing  data...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            SyncLoginData process = new SyncLoginData();
            process.execute();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data synced successfully....",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

SyncLoginData.java

```
public class SyncLoginData  extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
String data="";
String dataParsed = "";
DatabaseHelper mydb;

String singleParsed ="";
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1034t9");
        HttpURLConnection  httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        while(line != null){
            line =  bufferedReader.readLine();
            data = data + line;
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    Main2Activity.data.setText(this.data);
}
}
```

Comment: Your asynch task looks OK to me.  Where is `Main2Activity.data` being defined?  Before this, does the rest call you make return any text?

Comment: yes. sir. I didn't copied full code..

Comment: You didn't answer the second part of my question, and maybe you should include the full code.

Comment: On a side note, your toast in `btnsync`'s `OnClickListener` to indicate data was synced successfully isn't technically correct, as you're starting an AsyncTask before that. The toast will be shown immediately after your AsyncTask was started, regardless of whether your AsyncTask has finished or not.

Comment: how to check whether the data sync completed or not.. any condition for that

Comment: in `onPostExecute`, that's where your sync is considered complete.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
public class SyncLoginData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        String data;

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1034t9");
            HttpURLConnection  httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            while (line != null) {
                line =  bufferedReader.readLine();
                data = data + line;
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String data) {
        Main2Activity.data.setText(data);
    }
}
```